# Removing outer white space around a bar graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, formatting

It might be a bit of a simple question but on
[image: this graph] I want to remove the outer white space around the graph but I have no idea if its possible or how to do this. Any help woule be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The space to the left of the plot area is taken up by the Y-axis label. You can click it to select it, then delete it. Even when there's no label text, the text box is still there which prevents you from moving the plot area.

Select and delete the axis label, and you can move the plot area left a bit more, but you can't get it to the very left edge of the chart area.

Below, you can see I have the text box for the axis label selected, which I can then delete.

[image]

The plot area will always have a small border inside the chart area.